# find 4 consecutive rows with a specific value using a mysql query

Tags: mysql

My table has 4 columns: id (autoincrement), machine (integer between 1 and 300), event (integer), status (string)

I need to run a query on this table, that returns the four machines with the lowest possible machine number where event="5" and status = "free" and that are consecutive numbers.

for example if machine 3 is busy, the query should NOT return 1,2,4,5 because they are not consequent. instead if machines 4,5,6,7 are free it should return those. It should NOT return 5,6,7,8 since it is not the lowest possible machinenumber. the lowest possible is 4,5,6,7.

```
select * from mytable where event="5" and status="free" order by machine asc limit 4
```

does exactly what i need, except that it does return all rows, not taking into account that they MUST be consequent in the machines column.

Can this be done?

```
sample data as requested:

id - machine - event - status
22      1        5      free
23      2        5      free
24      3        5      busy
25      4        5      busy
26      5        5      free  *
27      6        5      free  *
28      7        5      free  *
29      8        5      free  *
30      9        5      free
31      10       5      busy
32      11       5      free
```

The lines marked with * are the lines i would need to get. the first 4 consecutive rows on column machine, with status value free and event id = 5.

Comment: can you explain through example

Comment: Show some sample data or use rextester

Comment: posted sample data as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(machine ORDER BY machine),',',4) as machines FROM
(SELECT machine,
CASE WHEN machine=@machine + 1 THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
    @machine := machine As m
  FROM
    t, (SELECT @n:=0) r, (SELECT @machine := '') z
WHERE event=5 and status="free"
  ORDER BY
    id) sub
    GROUP BY g 
    HAVING COUNT(*) >=4
```

If you want ALL the rows

```
SELECT t.id,t.machine,t.event,t.status FROM
(SELECT id,machine,event,status,GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) gr FROM
(SELECT *,
CASE WHEN machine=@machine + 1 THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
    @machine := machine As m
  FROM
    t, (SELECT @n:=0) r, (SELECT @machine := '') z
WHERE event=5 and status="free"
  ORDER BY
    id) sub
    GROUP BY g 
    HAVING COUNT(*) >=4) o
JOIN t ON FIND_IN_SET(t.id,gr)
ORDER BY id LIMIT 4
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/ZQMS83578)

[Test2](http://rextester.com/ULEWS32464)

Comment: thank you, marked as accepted.. would it be possible to add a modification`? so that the first of the four machines, must be divisible by 4... so it would pick 4,5,6,7 or 8,9,10,11 but not 6,7,8,9 or so.. just as a plus.

Comment: thank you! mind explaining your query? So I can edit to my needs.. also, is this query quite intensive? what columns should I index?

Comment: @sharkyenergy It uses the MOD() function to check for divisibility with 4 and MIN() to get the first or minimum machine value.As to indexes id should have one but I`m guessing it is a primary key so it has one already.Also maybe add an index on machines. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-mod-function.php

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should do the trick

```
select  t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t4.id
from    (select * from mytable where event="5" and status="free") t1
join    (select * from mytable where event="5" and status="free") t2
on      t1.id + 1 = t2.id
join    (select * from mytable where event="5" and status="free") t3
on      t1.id + 2 = t3.id
join    (select * from mytable where event="5" and status="free") t4
on      t1.id + 3 = t4.id
order by t1.id
limit 1
```

May require some tweaking on the join conditions (hard to tell without examples).

Comment: Thanks, will test it asap. posted sampel code in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

this depends a little on the size of your dataset, but for small datasets this should work:

```
select * from mytable m1 where m1.event="5" and m1.status="free" 
and(m1.machine-1 in (select machine from mytable where event="5" and status="free") 
and m1.machine-2 in (select machine from mytable where event="5" and status="free") 
and m1.machine-3 in (select machine from mytable where event="5" and status="free") 
OR( m1.machine+1 in (select machine from mytable where event="5" and status="free") 
and m1.machine+2 in (select machine from mytable where event="5" and status="free") 
and m1.machine+3 in (select machine from mytable where event="5" and status="free") )
order by m1.machine asc limit 4
```

for larger datasets, you'll want to use a JOIN to accomplish the same.

you can also just use the second half to find the first instance and then start your query from there.